# Is $ED=DF⇒E=F$ (matrices) correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am to prove or find a counterexample for the following problem:
Let $A, B, C, D, F \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. If $D^{-1}(A+B+C)D=F$ is correct then $A=F-B-C$ is correct.

I have not found a counterexample though there might be one - I don't know. This is how far I get:

Let $E=A+B+C$. Then the problem can be expressed as "If $D^{-1}ED=F$ is correct then $E=F$ is correct." Also, $D^{-1}ED=F \Leftrightarrow ED=DF$

But I have no clue how I could show $ED=DF \Rightarrow E=F$.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: You cannot prove $ED=DF \Rightarrow E=F$ because in general it is not true. Check out matrix similarity.

Comment: @tst Do you have a counterexample for me?

Comment: It is easy to cook up counter examples once you know what's going on. Do read about matrix similarity (or matrix diagonalization). It will make this very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $E=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $F=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ should work as a counterexample.

Comment: This would only work for $D=0$ which is not allowed because it is not part of the general linear group, or am I mistaken?

Comment: You are mistaken.

Comment: To clarify: You are right, $D=0$ is not part of the general linear group, but there is another $D$ such that $D^{-1}ED=F$.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Try simple $2\times 2$ counterexamples. There is also counterexample where $B=C=0$.

Comment: $B$ and $C$ are non-zero, since they're from $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Then try $B=-C=I_n$.